# snmp mib for monitoring service instance counters

Tags: cisco, snmp, evc

in career ethernet switches like ME3600, we can configure EVC as defined in MEF.
evc counters(service instance counters) are as follow:
rx_green_frames;  rx_green_bytes;       rx_yellow_frames; rx_yellow_bytes;      rx_red_frames;     rx_red_bytes;        rx_discard_frames; rx_discard_bytes;    tx_discard_frames;tx_discard_bytes;     tx_green_frames;   tx_green_bytes;      tx_yellow_frames; tx_yellow_bytes;
Is there standard snmp mib table for monitoring these counters?

Comment: Cisco does provide CISCO-EVC-MIB (SNMPv1&2) and CISCO-EVC-CAPABILITIES (v2 only). That's where I'd start looking. However not all devices support all MIBs in all SW levels - for example as per ME 3800X and ME 3600X release 12.2(52)EY config guide neither of these is supported on that platform. Supported MIBs listed at the end of the manual.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but none of them show evc counters. these counters explained in mef40 and exist in mef-uni-evc-mib. my question is: is there any snmp mib table except this for monitoring counters.

Comment: mef-uni-evc-mib section MefServicePerformanceEntry contains frame and octet counter entries for ingress, egress and discards. So what exactly are you missing? Is the problem that your device or application doesn't support this mib, and you're looking for an alternative mib your device or application would support? Or something entirely different?

Comment: this mip just monitor counters for the services have bwp configuration, and does not support monitoring services counters without attaching serivce policy for service instance. Its indexes are mefServiceBwpGrpCfgIndex and mefServiceBwpCfgIndex.

I am looking for a mib which has been monitoring service instances counters with or without using BWP.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I'm sorry but this goes now beyond my ken. Might I suggest that you clarify your initial question? You should add what you're here teaching me about these specific mib and the counters within, and what exactly is it you're looking for and for what purpose. Your current question is too wide, usually explaining what exactly you need and why gets you much better answers :-)